# Cannot Run or Debug C# tests with CodeLens in VSCode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run my xUnit tests within VSCode using the Run CodeLens
[image: A Picture of the CodeLens].

I am using VSCode 1.65.0 with .Net 6 (6.0.200) on a 2019 MacBook Pro (Intel) with the v1.24.1 of the C# VSCode extension.

I have run it using the `dotnet test` command, the .NET Core Test Explore Plugin and VS2022, and these work as expected.

This is the output log I get

```
----- Running test method "net6TestTest.TestControllerTest.Get_ShouldReturn_String" -----

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.1.0+ae57d105c for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error MSB3883: Unexpected exception:  [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error : DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/bin/Debug/net6.0/ref/net6Test.dll'. [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter) [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode) [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize) [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, Boolean overwrite) [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite) [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.CopyRefAssembly.Copy() [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :  [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error MSB3883: Unexpected exception:  [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error : DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/bin/Debug/net6.0/ref/net6Test.dll'. [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter) [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode) [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize) [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, Boolean overwrite) [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite) [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.CopyRefAssembly.Copy() [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :  [/Users/ssmale/Projects/net6Test/net6Test/net6Test.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.26
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use .net 6 you need to update the Omnisharp setting to use the 'modern' way

the setting you need to toggle is `omnisharp.useModernNet`. it is described in the reads of the C# extension.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me! I had a problem debugging tests "Failed to run test because Failed to connect to the dotnet test process."
Setting omnisharp.useModernNet=true and restart of VS Code solved the issue

Comment: A note for M1 Mac users: it appears you'll need to install the arm64 SDK rather than the emulated x64 version for this to work. https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5008#issuecomment-1027711421