# Unit Testing Works in VSCode on Windows but not Linux

Tags: linux, debugging, visual-studio-code, .net-core, xunit

I'm having trouble debugging Xunit unittests in .NET6 running on Ubuntu 20.04 in VSCode (1.66.2). These run in VisualStudio and VSCode in Windows. I can run (not debug) the tests in Linux from the CLI or the [.NET Core Test Explorer](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-dotnet-test-explorer) extension.

If I try to debug the unittest with the context menu or the little magic command attribute that is placed above the unittest method declaration, I get an error:

```
Failed to start debugger: 
"System.InvalidOperationException: The debugger could not be started
at OmniSharp.DotNetTest.Services.DebugTestService.Handle 
(OmniSharp.DotNetTest.Models.DebugTestGetStartInfoRequest request) [0x00050] in <9d87b466e5a04dffb95becc0b4dfd560>:0
at OmniSharp.Endpoint.Exports.RequestHandlerExportHandler`2[TRequest,TResponse].Handle (TRequest request) [0x00000] in <3d93fabea6954f4ba147450b0cf4332a>:0
at OmniSharp.Endpoint.EndpointHandler`2[TRequest,TResponse].GetFirstNotEmptyResponseFromHandlers (OmniSharp.Endpoint.Exports.ExportHandler`2[TRequest,TResponse][] handlers, TRequest request) [0x00022] in <3d93fabea6954f4ba147450b0cf4332a>:0
at OmniSharp.Endpoint.EndpointHandler`2[TRequest,TResponse].HandleRequestForLanguage (System.String language, TRequest request, OmniSharp.Protocol.RequestPacket packet) [0x00163] in <3d93fabea6954f4ba147450b0cf4332a>:0
at OmniSharp.Endpoint.EndpointHandler`2[TRequest,TResponse].Process (OmniSharp.Protocol.RequestPacket packet, OmniSharp.Endpoint.LanguageModel model, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken requestObject) [0x0024b] in <3d93fabea6954f4ba147450b0cf4332a>:0
at OmniSharp.Stdio.Host.HandleRequest (System.String json, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger) [0x000f3] in <2584067dfcea42a69c19a025cfbc4799>:0 "
```

I also see this in the OUTPUT pane:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error MSB3883: Unexpected exception:  [/home/danielp/Source/Experiments/LibAndTest/Library/Library.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error : DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/home/danielp/Source/Experiments/LibAndTest/Library/bin/Debug/net6.0/ref/Library.dll'. [/home/danielp/Source/Experiments/LibAndTest/Library/Library.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter) [/home/danielp/Source/Experiments/LibAndTest/Library/Library.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode) [/home/danielp/Source/Experiments/LibAndTest/Library/Library.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize) [/home/danielp/Source/Experiments/LibAndTest/Library/Library.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, Boolean overwrite) [/home/danielp/Source/Experiments/LibAndTest/Library/Library.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite) [/home/danielp/Source/Experiments/LibAndTest/Library/Library.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.CopyRefAssembly.Copy() [/home/danielp/Source/Experiments/LibAndTest/Library/Library.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.202/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4650,5): error :  [/home/danielp/Source/Experiments/LibAndTest/Library/Library.csproj]
```

What I find interesting here is that it keeps looking for referenced dlls in `...Debug/net6.0/ref/Library.dll'` and there is no build output binary placed there much less a folder called `ref`.

For now, I can debug w/ a console app, but it sure seems strange that this works so well in Windows but not Linux. However, now that I say that out loud: it seems like it shouldn't be that surprising.

Lastly, I did try debugging mstest unittests w/ the same results.

Comment: You should tag your language. C# I assume?

Comment: This isn't dependent on the .NET language, just the version of .NET (Core).

Comment: Then you should add a .NET tag, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! But only because I found this other answered question:
[Cannot Run or Debug C# tests with CodeLens in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71356435/cannot-run-or-debug-c-sharp-tests-with-codelens-in-vscode)

Because I'm running .NET 6, the Omnisharp extension needed a settings change:

- Open your VSCode extensions w/ the icon on the left
- Search for `Omnisharp` in the text box
- Click the gear icon and choose `Extension Settings` from the resulting context menu
- Up top in the search bar that is revealed in the settings page, append (w/ a space) `modern` so that the search bar contains `@ext:ms-dotnettools.csharp modern`
- You will see a checkbox labeled `Omnisharp: Use Modern Net.`

  - Make sure this is checked.
- I had to restart VSCode and allow the extension to do a download

After that it works.

[image]

Comment: I might add that this does not seem like a difference in Linux vs. Windows other than the Omnisharp setting seems to have had to have been set manually. I've never had to set this using VSCode in Windows since I've started poking around w/ .NET 6.